# Custom choices in JavaScript confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, dialog, confirm

How to write a confirm dialog in JavaScript with custom choices?

Instead of just "Ok" and "Cancel", I would like to have for example "This" "That" and "Other".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show confirmation alert with three buttons 'Yes' 'No' and 'Cancel' as it shows in MS Word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091001/how-to-show-confirmation-alert-with-three-buttons-yes-no-and-cancel-as-it)

Comment: Regarding possible duplicate - I'd like to point out that this question was written two years earlier ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In short, you can't.

You might want to consider looking into using something like a [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) instead.

Answer (score 4):

You could ask the user for an answer using:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Question");
```

You could loop that sentence until the user enters an answer within the valid ones.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.
Use some javascript UI (jQuery UI, YUI, Mootools) library and mimic a dialog you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
// custom Confirm builder
function OnConfirm(text, func) {

    var _confirm = $('<div/>').addClass('confirm');
    _confirm.append($('<h2/>').text(text));

    _confirm.append('<br/><br/>');

    var _btnCancel = $('<input/>').attr('type', 'button').val('cancel')
        .bind('click', function () {
            $(this).parent('.confirm').hide();
            func(false);
        });

    var _btnApply = $('<input/>').attr('type', 'button').val('OK')
        .bind('click', function () {
            $(this).parent('.confirm').hide();
            func(true);
        });

    _confirm.append(_btnCancel);
    _confirm.append(_btnApply);
    $('body').append(_confirm);
}

$(function () { // documen.loaded
    $('#testLink').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); ;
        var _href = $(this).attr('href');
        var _title = $(this).attr('title');
        // call custom confirm function with callback function
        OnConfirm(_title, function (_isContinue) {               
                if (_isContinue) {
                    location.href = _href;
                }
            }
        );
    });
});
```