# javascript confirm function customisation

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [custom choices in javascript confirm dialog.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800033/custom-choices-in-javascript-confirm-dialog)

```
function confirmdel(msg) 
{
 var agree=confirm(msg);
 if (agree)
   return true ;
 else
  return false ;
}
```

this is general delete confirmation java script function ,

it ask to user,

Hit

Confirmation dialog box with Ok or Cancel ,

I want to change this ok cancel buttons to Continue and Dont-continue ,

Is it possible ,

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, the `confirm` dialog can't be customized.

You would have to resort to a custom dialog box solution, like [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) or (relatively big) [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation).

Note that those dialog solutions often work slightly differently than `confirm` in that they don't return a "yes / no" value, but require you to bind events to the dialog's buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some javascript-based popups with custom message and custom buttons. For example,
[jquery ui modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation)  or [modal popups](http://www.modalpopups.com/).