# JavaScript confirm box with custom buttons

Tags: javascript, confirmbutton

Can I write a custom confirm box in JavaScript that, instead of the default `OK` and `CANCEL` button, shows a `SAVE` and `DELETE` button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [custom choices in javascript confirm dialog.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800033/custom-choices-in-javascript-confirm-dialog)

Comment: I recommend not to use JavaScripts `confirm()`, `alert()` or `prompt()` commands, since those are blocking the whole browser thread (in most browsers). You should use a JavaScript-UI alternative.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [jQuery UI Dialog Box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) for this.

You can do something like this:

JS:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Do it": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://jqueryui.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
<link href="http://jqueryui.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jqueryui.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Is it treason, then?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span>Am I the Senate?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Not with the native JavaScript confirm box. You could use one of the many JavaScript UI components that emulate modal dialogs to do this instead.

Here's an example: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

I've never used this so use at your own risk.

Comment: link is no longer active

Answer (score 3):

```
$('confirm text').dialog(
    {
        modal:true, //Not necessary but dims the page background
        buttons:{
            'Save':function() {
                //Whatever code you want to run when the user clicks save goes here
             },
             'Delete':function() {
                 //Code for delete goes here
              }
        }
    }
);
```

This should work, but you will need to download or link to jQuery and the jQuery UI libraries to run this.