# Confirmbox with custom button text

Tags: javascript, html

when we use confirm prompt box , it always display "ok" and "cancel" buttons

I want to change the label text for the ok and cancel buttons as Agree and Not Agree

please do suggest any solution

Comment: You can't do that with native ones. But there are few workaroungs available, google it

Comment: You can check any other prompts like modal popups or etc...

Comment: try for a modal and provide your own text.

Comment: i think we can custom the prompt boxes, as we doing in all progming langs. we can extend the properties of confirm box and do the changes.

Answer (score 0):

What i can suggest you is apply or override CSS; which i think is not at all a better solution.
Next you can go with following link posted below.

[JavaScript confirm box with custom buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976272/javascript-confirm-box-with-custom-buttons).

Hope this helps.