# Adding a Windows Popup at load with custom button

Tags: html, javascript

We have upgraded and application and want to add the following at the load of previous application

Giving users two options where they can click one button to go to new and other

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.confirm('STOP AND READ CAREFULLY Application has been upgraded to New Version click "OK" and you would be directed to New URL Click Cancel to go to Old Version')) 
{window.location.href='https://www.google.com/?client=safari';};
</script>
```

Right now it's just giving my OK and CANCEL button i would like the ability to format the text "STOP AND READ CAREFULLY Application has been upgraded to New Version click "OK" and you would be directed to New URL Click Cancel to go to Old Version" in multi line and also if possible rename OK and CANCEL to NEW or OLD

Regards

Comment: You really have no control over styling or formatting a native `confirm` dialog. You'll have to create your own instead. Possible duplicate: [JavaScript confirm box with custom buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976272/javascript-confirm-box-with-custom-buttons) (While the answers here suggest jQuery UI, I'd suggest a non-jQuery approach like **[SweetAlert](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)**)

Comment: I reviewed those and I can't figure out how I can use in my application