# alert popup before delete using jquery in ascx page for link button calling in onClientClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

please help me in creating a alert before deleting a row in gridview, as for my requirement i created a grid in ascx page and calling in aspx page. I have a LinkButton for deleting and the functionality is working fine but i'm unable to get a popup warning before delete. If i use "return confirmation('alert before delete')" it's working fine, instead of alert i need a popup

please help me thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind an event to that links using,

```
$(document).on("click", ".classnameoflink", function () { 
    //code for pop up 

    });
```

**Edit**

```
$(document).on("click", ".DeleteUserRow", function() {
$("#message").html("Are you sure you want to delete User?");
$("#dialog").dialog({
    title: "Delete Confirmation",
    buttons: {
        Ok: function () {},
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            return false;
        }
    },
    modal: true
});
});
```

make sure that, `DeleteUserRow` is the same rendered class name of that link button.

Comment: i'm unable to write a class in it can i use ID instead..!!

Comment: is that an anchor tag?

Comment: $(document).on("click", "a", function () { }); use like this, and see if it works or not

Comment: it's an <asp:LinkButton/>

Comment: yes i'm using below code, i'm unable to get popup

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", ".DeleteUserRow", function UserDel() {
    $("#message").html("Are you sure you want to delete User?");
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        title: "Delete Confirmation",
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {

            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                return false;
            }
        },
        modal: true
    });

    });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091001/how-to-show-confirmation-alert-with-three-buttons-yes-no-and-cancel-as-it) it many help you.

I am using 3 buttons instead of using 3 button you can use Ok and Cancel.