# show an dialog onclick with radiobuttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating an practice exam for some students in my school. I have a lot of multiple choice questions and i'm trying to get it to work bud got stuck here. I am new to javascript and have no clue on how to get this working. So every question has 4 choices that look like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <figures1></figures1>
    </td>
    <td class="questiona">
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a"/>a<br>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b"/>b<br>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c"/>c<br>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="d"/>d<br>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The question is just an image and they have to select either a, b, c or d. 
I've managed to get it working this far, bud what i want to add is an dialog whenever they click on a, b, c or d to tell them if the answer is correct or not and if not add a feedback to tell them why the answer is wrong. The reason why i am not using alert to give them a feedback is because i can't add images to an alert box.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `figures1` isn't a valid HTML element.

Comment: shouldv'e put that in the code, figures1 referrs to an array of figures. It just loads an image to the html page, the figure displays the question.

Comment: Btw, your students can see the right answers from the source code

Comment: It is an exam for practice only so it doesn't matter if they can view the answers, the goal of this exam is for them to learn.

Comment: @olli.puljula not all students are smart :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your input a class like "answer".
Then in your jquery code:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".answer").click(function(){
            ValidateAnswerFunction(this); //sends the input element to the validate answer function
            $( "#dialog" ).css("display", "block"); // shows the dialog .hide(); to hide it!
        });

       $("#dialog").click(function(){
           $(this).hide();
       });
    });

   function ValidateAnswerFunction(input){
       switch($(input).val()){
           case "a":
               $("#dialog").html("correct");
               break;
           case "b":
               $("#dialog").html("close");
               break;
           case "c":
               $("#dialog").html("not even close <img src='http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg' style='width:100px;height:100px'>");
               break;
           case "d":
               $("#dialog").html("are you even trying m8?");
               break;
       }
   }
```

Where #dialog is your dialog:

```
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdtwywgc/4/)

Comment: Well, having these `#dialog` and `.answer` you should probably add a full example how it is supposed to work.

Comment: @Regent true let me edit.

Comment: hmm it looks great, bud the thing is i want to have 4 different feedbacks on the questions, like if he answers a show him feedback of a and b show feedback of b etc.

Comment: @rickert I'll update my answer and jsfiddle to suit your needs :)

Comment: @Stijn Bernards wow thanks alot it's great. One last little question :P Is it possible to put images inside the feedback? It are questions about different welding machines etc. and if they answer it wrong i would like to show them an image of the answer they chose.

Comment: @rickert Yes Inside the .html('') just put a image tag like this: .html('<img src="yourimage">'). I'll update my jsfiddle a little bit.

Comment: @rickert Updated it don't forget to set the answer to accepted to help future users!

Comment: @StijnBernards thank you so much, just did it :)

Comment: @rickert You're welcome feel free to ask anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to test the value of the clicked element and then give feedback from that answer. This can be done i varity of ways, but I'd say that using `$("[name=q1]").click()` would be the easiest, and then use `$(this).val()` to check the answer.

Please refer to this fiddle for an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/u3csoave/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `confirmation alert` to achieve this.there are too many `jquery demo's` available.

for example see this link:[how to show confirmation alert with three buttons 'Yes' 'No' and 'Cancel' as it shows in MS Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091001/how-to-show-confirmation-alert-with-three-buttons-yes-no-and-cancel-as-it)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use confirmation alert to show user correct answer and put a link in the alert box which allows them to change their answer.

Answer (score 0):

JQueryUI dialog..

```
function foobar() {
   $("#dialog").dialog();
}

<div id="dialog" title="Dialog title">
   <img src="foo.bar"/>
</div>
```

Then open dialogs in radiobuttons' onlick method.

Maybe you should just make one generic dialog and pass all the information needed as parameters so you don't end up with a page containing multiple dialogs.