# Javascript Alert with listed options, and callback

Tags: javascript, java

Does Javascript have something similar to the alert builder in Java, I want to have a button that when clicked displays an alert with a set of options and when the option is clicked it triggers a callback with passing the selected option?

Or am I going to be looking at putting some sort of Java call in my code to pass the response back?

Comment: Check out paper-dialog element [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple confirm dialog you can do something like this:

JavaScript

```
if(confirm("Should I do it?")) 
{ 
   console.log("Go for it");
}
```

Otherwise you should probably look at something like jQueryUI to make modal dialogs.

Comment: I want more than 2 options, I want 6

Comment: Then go with @JoeBorg's example and use jQueryUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can check http://bootboxjs.com/ that does prompting with callbacks.

Unless its a simple confirm with a yes or not, you will have to use a library\write your own plugin.

Answer (score 0):

this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StriplingWarrior/vcZMF/) is what you're after, by StriplingWarrior. Basically it requires jquery UI dialog plugin, and like that you can have multiple inputs and handle input events right there on declaration

```
buttons: {
   "Yes": function() {
      alert('you chose yes');
   },
   "No": function() {
      alert('you chose no');
   },
   "Cancel": function() {
      dialog.dialog('close');
   }
}
```

A similar question was asked here: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091001/how-to-show-confirmation-alert-with-three-buttons-yes-no-and-cancel-as-it)