# javascript confirmation button with three buttons

Tags: javascript

How can I create a JavaScript for function confirmation with three buttons without using any html code at all?

The JavaScript function will be caller from another system so I can just use a js function without any html or jQuery.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "JavaScript for function confirmation with three buttons without using any html code at all?" You really need to clarify this. Do you mean explicitly not writing in HTML, but you're able to append elements from JS? What do you mean "function confirmation"? Do you have any base code? This is a badly written question and the answers are all over the place because of it.

Answer (score 1):

Without any HTML (which also would implicate all JS dialogs)... simply said, you can't.

If you are willing to implement a JS solution, you might find [your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9091077/881032).