# Javascript Customize Confirm with "Yes" or "No"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I have a Javascript confirm() box with "Yes" or "No" instead of the default "Ok" or "Cancel" ?

Comment: You cant do this out of the box. You'd have to make your own dialog.

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217063/custom-js-confirm-modals-using-jquery-deferred-and-issues-with-return-values-bas/18374548#18374548)

Comment: I made my own confirm dialog because i dont like the standard one. https://github.com/stein189/YesNoDialog its really simpel to use and you can adjust it as you wish

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The javascript confirm dialog cannot be customized.

If you require dialog customization I would suggest looking at [JQuery UI - Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

Answer (score 4):

You **cannot do it with standard javascript**.

You have this workaround for **IE only** ([source](http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/javascript/f1172.shtml)):

```
<script language=javascript>

/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if (@_win32 && @_jscript_version>=5)

function window.confirm(str)
{
    execScript('n = msgbox("'+str+'","4132")', "vbscript");
    return(n == 6);
}

@end @*/
var r = confirm("Can you do it?");
alert(r);
</script>
```

Or, you can use custom [dialog from jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply i think you can't. There are a lot of answers about that on stack overflow, for example this one : [custom choices in javascript confirm dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800033/custom-choices-in-javascript-confirm-dialog) that states it. If you want to do it, you have to use your own dialogs like those of jquery ui

Answer (score 0):

Today, you can do it simply with javascript. There's is a simple js library called [notiejs](https://github.com/jaredreich/notie.js) that has a confirm option.

With a simple line

```
notie.confirm('Title text', 'Yes button text', 'No button text', yes_callback)
```

you can have a custom confirm box. (Maybe the style or the interaction won't fit your use case but I'm just pointing out that it is possible).