# Yes/No buttons instead of OK/Cancel in a confirm() dialog?

Tags: javascript, air, webkit

In an Adobe AIR (HTML/JS) app, is it possible to display <kbd>Yes</kbd>/<kbd>No</kbd> buttons, instead of <kbd>OK</kbd>/<kbd>Cancel</kbd> in a `confirm()` dialog?

Anything that works with [webkit](/questions/tagged/webkit) should work.

Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/823790/1563422), but all of the answers utilise jQuery, which I don't want to add just for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe so. In JS, `confirm()` is specified to only use the <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> buttons.

If you want something more complicated, you'll have to make your own dialog, or use a third-party one that provides your desired functionality (yes, including jQuery, unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to customise the `confirm()` dialog.

There are some suggestions at [Javascript Customize Confirm with "Yes" or "No"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937761/javascript-customize-confirm-with-yes-or-no) but it pins down to using jQuery or implementing your own version of the jQuery dialog.

Answer (score 1):

The closest native solution I can think about is using the new [<dialog> element.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog)

The following example is the simplest one taken from the link above, as the dialog is made of HTML you can customize it as you want. Browse the link for advanced examples.

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector("dialog");
const showButton = document.querySelector("dialog + button");
const closeButton = document.querySelector("dialog button");

// "Show the dialog" button opens the dialog modally
showButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.showModal();
});

// "Close" button closes the dialog
closeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.close();
});
```

```css
::backdrop {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    magenta,
    rebeccapurple,
    dodgerblue,
    green
  );
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<dialog>
  <button autofocus>Close</button>
  <p>This modal dialog has a groovy backdrop!</p>
</dialog>
<button>Show the dialog</button>
```