# How to change the values from "yes" and "no" to other in data confirm in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using the link to delete the record below is the code that I have used

```
<%= link_to product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }%>
```

when I click on the click alert box will open with the values "ok" to proceed and "Canel" to reject.
So my question how do I change the "ok" to "Yes" and "cancel" to "reject" in the alert box.
Below is the image for the reference

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1800059/297087

Comment: This is native browser behaviour. You have no control how it looks on different devices/browsers. If you want totally custom control for the dialogue box, you need to implement it yourself instead.

Comment: It's like asking "how do I change a native datepicker?", or "how do I change a native number-field input behaviour?". You should either embrace it, or not use it at all. **For example**, the built-in browser behaviour will take into account the user's language settings, and will behave differently on mobile vs desktop.

Comment: By the way, your image is quite confusing. If the default buttons are "Yes"/"Cancel", and you want to change this to "OK"/"Reject", then why did you show us a half-changed version of "OK"/"Cancel"?

Comment: @TomLord that first comment is pretty much an answer to the question.

Comment: @TomLord sorry man I have updated the question.. and your first comment - I was not aware of that... so basically I wanted fully customize alert box now I switched to sweet alert